# How to hide Title in `Theme.Sherlock.Dialog`?

Tags: android, dialog, styles, actionbarsherlock

My DialogActivities extends from SherlockFragmentActivity. So I must to use Sherlock themes.
In `values-v14` I hide Title like this:

```
<style name="Theme.Sherlock.Dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

How to hide Title in `Theme.Sherlock.Dialog` in `values` folder?

By default it looks like this ([github.com](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/res/values/abs__themes.xml)):

```
<style name="Theme.Sherlock.Dialog" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogWindowTitle.Sherlock</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/abs__dialog_full_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>

    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.6</item>

    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abs__primary_text_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/abs__primary_text_holo_light</item>

    <item name="windowMinWidthMajor">@dimen/abs__dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="windowMinWidthMinor">@dimen/abs__dialog_min_width_minor</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I believe all of Sherlock's theme configuration are _outside_ of the `android:` namespace. Can you try simply `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`

Comment: `<style name="Theme.Sherlock.Dialog" parent="android:Theme"><item name="windowNoTitle">true</item></style>` - gives me an error: _You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative._

Comment: it should have been: `<style name="Theme.Sherlock.Dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item><item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>`

Comment: Notice one is missing `android:`

Comment: It gives me same error on android 2.3.4 - _You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**
I've changed `abs__dialog_title_holo.xml` by adding two lines in: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/res/layout/abs__dialog_title_holo.xml

```
<com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.FakeDialogPhoneWindow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<TextView android:id="@android:id/title" style="?android:attr/windowTitleStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abs__alert_dialog_title_height"
    android:visibility="gone" //******** FIRST ******** 
    android:paddingLeft="16dip"
    android:paddingRight="16dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />
<View android:id="@+id/abs__titleDivider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" //******** SECOND ********
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="@color/abs__holo_blue_light" />
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:foreground="?attr/windowContentOverlay">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/abs__content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```